# Como fazer o modulo Mapper no EF?

Tags: entity-framework

Como fazer o modulo Mapper no EmptyFramework 1 para n em duas duas tabelas?

```
Tabela 1

- clienteID          
- nome              
- endereçoID
```

---

```
Tabela 2    

- EndereçoID       
- rua
- bairro      
- cidade
```

Comment: Um Cliente pode ter um endereço ou vários? desculpa ficou estranho isso? até coloquei uma resposta mas, posso alterar !

Comment: somente um é que não posso usar o nome verdadeiros dos campos

Comment: Bruno então na minha resposta é a primeira parte, dê uma olhada e adeque ao seu modo real ai!

Comment: Deu uns erro de exceções aqui, vou estrutura melhor com o código que já tenho e posta aqui.

Comment: quando se coloca a duvida deve atentar ao seguinte: que ela reflita ao seu modelo e que possa entender, se não pode colocar nome de campos fica complicado, mas, tente assemelhar ao que foi feito. Coloque o modelo real na sua pergunta, isso é bobeira não colocar!

Comment: Foi o que tentei mais está muito mais complexo que imagine que leva a varias ligações que já estão prontas

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61548/discussion-between-bruno-h-and-virgilio-novic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Eu entendi diferente o seu relacionamento, não seria agregação no* `Entity Framework`, *se sim é dessa forma*:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }        
    public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
}
public class Endereco
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public string Rua { get; set; }
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }  
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

***Configurações da relação de agregação:***

```
public class ClienteConfiguration : 
        System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<Cliente>
{
    public ClienteConfiguration()
        : this("dbo")
    {
    }

    public ClienteConfiguration(string schema)
    {
        ToTable("Cliente", schema);
        HasKey(x => x.ClienteId);

        Property(x => x.ClienteId)
            .HasColumnName("ClienteID")
            .HasColumnType("int")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System
                    .ComponentModel
                    .DataAnnotations
                    .Schema
                    .DatabaseGeneratedOption
                    .Identity);         
        Property(x => x.Nome)
            .HasColumnName("Nome")
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .IsRequired()
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasMaxLength(50);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class EnderecoConfiguration : 
        System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<Endereco>
{
    public EnderecoConfiguration()
        : this("dbo")
    {
    }

    public EnderecoConfiguration(string schema)
    {
        ToTable("Endereco", schema);
        HasKey(x => x.ClienteId);

        Property(x => x.ClienteId)
            .HasColumnName("ClienteID")
            .HasColumnType("int")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System
                    .ComponentModel
                    .DataAnnotations
                    .Schema
                    .DatabaseGeneratedOption,
                    .None);
        Property(x => x.Rua)
            .HasColumnName("Rua")
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .IsRequired()
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(x => x.Bairro)
            .HasColumnName("Bairro")
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .IsRequired()
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(x => x.Cidade)
            .HasColumnName("Cidade")
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .IsRequired()
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        HasRequired(a => a.Cliente)
            .WithOptional(b => b.Endereco)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

*Agora se for 1 Cliente tem vários Endereços então muda completamente:*

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Endereco> Endereco { get; set; }
    public Cliente()
    {
        Endereco = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Endereco>();
    }
}
public class Endereco
{
    public int EnderecoId { get; set; }
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public string Rua { get; set; }
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

***Configuração da Relação (1:N)***

```
public class ClienteConfiguration : 
    System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<Cliente>
{
    public ClienteConfiguration()
        : this("dbo")
    {
    }

    public ClienteConfiguration(string schema)
    {
        ToTable("Cliente", schema);
        HasKey(x => x.ClienteId);

        Property(x => x.ClienteId)
            .HasColumnName("ClienteID")
            .HasColumnType("int")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System
                    .ComponentModel
                    .DataAnnotations
                    .Schema
                    .DatabaseGeneratedOption
                    .Identity);
        Property(x => x.Nome)
            .HasColumnName("Nome")
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .IsRequired()
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasMaxLength(50);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class EnderecoConfiguration : 
    System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<Endereco>
{
    public EnderecoConfiguration()
        : this("dbo")
    {
    }

    public EnderecoConfiguration(string schema)
    {
        ToTable("Endereco", schema);
        HasKey(x => x.EnderecoId);

        Property(x => x.EnderecoId)
            .HasColumnName("EnderecoID")
            .HasColumnType("int")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System
                    .ComponentModel
                    .DataAnnotations
                    .Schema
                    .DatabaseGeneratedOption
                    .Identity);
        Property(x => x.ClienteId)
            .HasColumnName("ClienteID")
            .HasColumnType("int")
            .IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.Rua)
            .HasColumnName("Rua")
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .IsRequired()
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(x => x.Bairro)
            .HasColumnName("Bairro")
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .IsRequired()
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(x => x.Cidade)
            .HasColumnName("Cidade")
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .IsRequired()
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        HasRequired(a => a.Cliente)
            .WithMany(b => b.Endereco)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ClienteId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Uma das duas pode ser o que procura, o que vale mesmo é entender qual você precisa muitas vezes fazer todos os campos na tabela `Cliente` seria o ideal, mas, a divisão dependendo dos casos também pode te servir muito bem, agora se um cliente pode ter vários endereços utilize a segunda opção.

---

*Configurando o* `DbContext` *para aplicação*:

```
public class MyDbContext: System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Cliente> Cliente { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Endereco> Endereco { get; set; }
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("Name=DatabaseEntities")
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClienteConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EnderecoConfiguration());
    }
}
```

***Referencias:***

- [Entity Framework – Usando Fluent API para definir relacionamentos](https://imasters.com.br/apis/entity-framework-usando-fluent-api-para-definir-relacionamentos/?trace=1519021197)
- [EF6 - Criando um relacionamento mestre-detalhe usando Code-First](http://www.macoratti.net/15/01/ef_mdcd1.htm)
- [Mapeamento com Entity Framework Code First (Fluent Api) – Parte 1](http://netcoders.com.br/mapeamento-com-entity-framework-code-first-fluent-api-parte-1/)
- [Mapeamento com Entity Framework Code First (Fluent Api) – Parte 2](http://netcoders.com.br/mapeamento-com-entity-framework-code-first-fluent-api-parte-2/)